# Which Continuous Integration Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tdd, junit, continuous-integration

I do a lot of TDD and am thinking of installing a Continuous Integration Plugin for Eclipse.

The two most popular seem to be JUnit Max and Infinitest.

As both are "payed for", I'd like some opinions on the pros/cons/otherwise of each. Maybe there is a "free" alternative that I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: as mentioned by Kent Beck himself, the [JUnit Max](http://www.junitmax.com/) project is [no longer actively developed](http://www.threeriversinstitute.org/blog/?p=291). This blog post [summarizes it](http://www.agilejava.eu/2009/07/17/junit-max-did-not-survive/) (July 2009):

> I wrote about JUnit Max in a previous post. In that post I commented that I was not sure if people were willing to pay $2/month for it. It turned out that I was right. Kent Beck just announced that he has deadpooled JUnit Max.

[Ken adds](http://www.threeriversinstitute.org/blog/?p=299):

> The conundrum I faced was how to market without any cash.
>   I do have my reputation–people will (briefly) listen to what I say. That’s why I used the media I used. Actually, if I had to do it over again I would attach my name less prominently to the product.
>   Some people bought Max because it was a tool I produced, not because it was a tool they really thought they needed, and that delayed clear feedback. The signal that clinched the decision to deadpool Max was the lack of word-of-mouth. Subscribers were telling their friends, but their friends weren’t buying.

That being said, he is planning to get JUnit Max back, as he said himself in a [vlog interview last week (July 2d, 2010)](http://blog.typemock.com/2010/07/video-kent-beck-on-junit-max-and-lean.html): (new release mid or end July?).

So, right now, for large workspaces with many large projects, [Infinitest](http://improvingworks.com/products/infinitest/) might scale better. (I have no direct experience with it).
It isn’t open source, but for personal use it should be possible get a free-of-charge [individual license](http://improvingworks.com/products/infinitest/for-individuals/). (see the [dual-licensing model for Infinitest](http://www.benrady.com/2009/07/dual-licensing-for-infinitest.html)).

Comment: Note to self: [twitter evaluation for "JUnit Max"](http://twitter.com/elefevre/status/19728852247): "JUnit Max is currently lacking a bit behind @infinitest. But with @kentbeck's name attached to it, it could sell to big accounts."

Comment: JUnit Max is officially alive again